# Angular: subscribing to a service via controller - subscription ignored

Tags: angular

I have checked several of the questions, but they seem a bit different than mine. I am currently creating a list of users, and rendering a link for each user. Upon clicking that user, a REST call will be made, returning an array of catalogs that the user will be able to see.

The *DatasourceService* looks like:

```
  getCatalogs(): Observable<Catalog[]> {
    const api_path = this.dataUrl + `metadata/getcatalogs/name/?user=${this.user.username}&password=${this.user.password}`;
    return this.http.get<Catalog[]>(api_path);
  }
```

which does in fact return the correct data.

Clicking a user runs this method:

```
  onSelect(user: User): void {
    this.selectedUser = user;
    this.datasourceService.user = user; // sets the user, as i can't figure out how to send it as a parameter, and subscribe to that call
    this.datasourceService.getCatalogs() // had to run this here so that the Observable would have at least one subscription to make it run.
      .subscribe(catalogs => {this.catalogs = catalogs; });
  }
```

I also have a *CatalogComponent* which looks like this:

```
@Input() user: User;
  public catalogs$: Observable<Catalog[]>;
  constructor(private datasourceService: DatasourceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.catalogs$ = this.datasourceService.getCatalogs();
    this.datasourceService.getCatalogs()
      .subscribe(catalogs => {this.catalogs = catalogs; });
  }
```

Which renders as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="user">

  <h3>Catalogs for User: {{user.username}}</h3>


    <ul >
      <li  *ngFor="let catalog of catalogs$ | async">
        {{ catalog.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

This is just the latest test, as I have tried several approaches to get this to work.

The problem I am having is that the catalogs fail to list, and it appears that the call isn't having any effect on the catalog controller;

Thinking that there might be two DatasourceServices running, I check that, and it's only declared in *app.module*

```
  providers: [DatasourceService],
```

Any help in getting this to work would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors? Also you can add err=>{} as second parameter in the subscriber. Better if you can create a code sample in statckblitz or somewhere.

Comment: You should show how you're using the catalog component in it's parent component,

Answer (score 0):

so you're subscribing to this observable 3 times for some reason, which means it will execute the data fetch 3 times, and it looks like you have a timing issue first and foremost.

My suspicion is that the user never gets set properly or not in time on the data service, so first, pass in the user as a parameter rather than setting and using it statefully:

```
  getCatalogs(user: User): Observable<Catalog[]> {
    const api_path = this.dataUrl + `metadata/getcatalogs/name/?user=${user.username}&password=${user.password}`;
    return this.http.get<Catalog[]>(api_path);
  }
```

Second, I'm not sure what you mean by this comment:

```
// had to run this here so that the Observable would have at least one subscription to make it run.
```

This doesn't make sense.  You subscribe in your CatalogComponent so there is no need to subscribe twice.  Just subscribe where you need the data.

The catalog component itself is very confusing.  You subscribe on init and set the result on the component, but then you don't use that result, you instead resubscribe with the async pipe to a separate stream definition.

Try doing it like this instead:

```
  @Input() user: User;
  public catalogs$: Observable<Catalog[]>;
  constructor(private datasourceService: DatasourceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.catalogs$ = this.datasourceService.getCatalogs(this.user);
  }
```

Now you just set your observable and subscribe via async, no need for the double subscription again.

Comment: Ok. i should have been a little more clear. I actually did exactly this when i first set it it . the problem i found was that the subscription was not working at all. Let me set it back up according your  answer, and see what happens. thanks!

Comment: also, the comment means that the the REST call won't be triggered unless something is subscribed to it. subscribing from the CatalogsComponent does not trigger the REST call when onSelect(user) is called.

Comment: You can see how that doesn’t make any sense. Where the call is made from / where you subscribe doesn’t make a difference. You’re not setting or passing the user correctly

Comment: Ok, I made the changes in bryan60's answer, and it no longer triggers the REST call. I am wondering if Angular is just not seeing the subscription. The CatalogComponent is being rendered inside the UserComponent, so I'm gonna take a look at Eliseo's answer. Thanks!

Comment: what you're saying doesn't make any sense, there is no concept of "angular not seeing the subscription", no offense, but this phrase is nonsense. the code posted here is correct. The issue is likely in how you pass / set the user in the cataglog component. You should post that code.

Comment: The observable isn't seeing any subscribers in the current state. i am passing the use like so: `<app-catalogs [user]="selectedUser">  </app-catalogs>`

Comment: Again, that does NOT make sense.  There is no concept of an observable "seeing" subscribers.  If you call subscribe then you subscribe, end of story.  The problem here is obvious though. You initialize the component before setting the user. so when you try to call your observable you have no user to pass, onInit runs when the component initializes, and not again.  This is likely generating an error when you try to subscribe since you pass a null reference. The other answer could be a solution but you will need to fix your template, easier might be to just wait till you have a user with ngIf

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding. I just started learning Angular yesterday. For some reason, I thought I read that if there were no subscribers to an Observable, the service would not make the REST call. The line of troubleshooting I was following was: if the REST call was not being made, the Observable might not see that it had no subscribers.

Comment: It is correct that an observable with no subscribers does not execute.  What is not correct is that some error can occur where your observable doesn't "see" subscribers, the observable is just a definition of how to handle a data stream.  If you call subscribe then you have subscribed to that stream and executed it, period. Your error is in how you are defining the data stream, not in how or where you are subscribing.

Comment: dang.. it looks like i am out of comments on this question.. stack overflow wants to move this to a chat instead.. I will just keep banging on this.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

the first take acount Bryan60 answer, simple pass a parameter

Second. If you're using a "child/parent", you must use @Input set to change the data - not the ngOnInit see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

```
@Input() 
  set user(value)
  {
    this.datasourceService.getCatalogs(value)
      .subscribe(catalogs => {this.catalogs = catalogs; });
  }
```

Comment: This makes sense. The CatalogComponent is called inside the user component:

Comment: In the end, since the catalogs component was embedded in the users component, I ended up using a blend of these two solutions. I used bryan60's to clean my source code, and use this solution to intercept the parent's value change and update the catalogs list. thanks so much, everyone..